# Syncsort Join two files

Tags: syncsort-dmx-h

I am trying to join two files based on a key and add a new column in the result based on a condition , but I am not able to figure out why my condition in command is not working. Please help me understand correct way of doing this.

**a.txt**

```
3~Y
4~0
1~Y
2~N
```

**b.txt**

```
4~44~444
3~33~333
2~22~222
1~11~111
```

**Syncsort Command**

```
/INFILE a.txt  ALIAS DOC '~' 3000
/JOINKEYS BA1
/FIELD DOC_Rest1 2:1 - 2:
/INFILE b.txt ALIAS FINACT '~' 3000
/JOINKEYS BA2
/FIELD FINACT_DID 2:1 - 2:
/FIELD FINACT_PILOT 3:1 - 3:
/FIELDS BA1 1:1 - 1:, BA2 1:1 - 1:
/COND CHKINCCALS (DOC_Rest1 = 'Y')
/DERIVEDFIELD  endofrecord '\n'
/DERIVEDFIELD TYPECAL
        If CHKINCCALS then FINACT_DID
        Else FINACT_PILOT
/OUTFILE c.txt OVERWRITE  /REFORMAT  LEFTSIDE:BA1,LEFTSIDE:DOC_Rest1, TYPECAL, endofrecord
/END
```

**Expected result**

```
1~Y~11~
2~N~222~
3~Y~33~
4~0~222~
```

**Actual result**

```
1~Y~Y~
2~N~~
3~Y~Y~
4~0~~
```

Answer (score 0):

After some guess work, I was able to figure out the correct way. I am still not sure how it works though.

```
/INFILE a.txt  ALIAS DOC '~' 3000
/JOINKEYS BA1
/FIELD DOC_Rest1 2:1 - 2:
/INFILE b.txt ALIAS FINACT '~' 3000
/JOINKEYS BA2
/FIELD FINACT_DID 2:1 - 2:
/FIELD FINACT_PILOT 3:1 - 3:
/FIELDS BA1 1:1 - 1:, BA2 1:1 - 1:
/COND CHKINCCALS (DOC_Rest1 = 'Y')
/DERIVEDFIELD  endofrecord '\n'
/DERIVEDFIELD TYPECAL
        If CHKINCCALS then RIGHTSIDE:FINACT_DID
        Else RIGHTSIDE:FINACT_PILOT
/OUTFILE c.txt OVERWRITE  /REFORMAT  LEFTSIDE:BA1,LEFTSIDE:DOC_Rest1, TYPECAL, endofrecord
/END
```

Comment: OK, thanks. So it looks like LEFTSIDE refers to your left half of the joined record, and RIGHTSIDE to the right half, which allows your field-definitions to be made using the data from file1, file2. Without the RIGHTSIDE you were picking up data again from file1, instead of from the same positions on file2. Do you have a manual? SyncSORT will provide copies as part of your license, so no reason not to.